# Unable to Import Turicreate into Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, valueerror, turi-create

When I try to import turicreate into Jupyter I receive the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1b519f14fefb> in <module>
----> 1 import turicreate

~/kazuha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/turicreate/__init__.py in <module>
     17 from turicreate.version_info import __version__
     18 
---> 19 from turicreate.data_structures.sgraph import Vertex, Edge
     20 from turicreate.data_structures.sgraph import SGraph
     21 from turicreate.data_structures.sarray import SArray

~/kazuha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 from . import image
---> 18 from . import sframe
     19 from . import sarray
     20 from . import sgraph

~/kazuha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/sframe.py in <module>
     29 
     30 import array
---> 31 from prettytable import PrettyTable
     32 from textwrap import wrap
     33 import datetime
```

I used pip list to ensure I'm using Jupyter from the same environment where I downloaded turicreate, and it checked out. This error occured after I uninstalled and reinstalled turicreate through Jupyter because turicreate.SFrame() was not functioning properly. I am quite new to programming and would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't paste the entire error traceback? What does it say below what you show? Based on what you've share I suggest you make a new cell and try to run `%pip install prettytable` in the notebook where you are trying to use `turicreate`. After that, restart the kernel and then try `import turicreate`?